# How to select data series with special steps by Dataframe.rolling in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime, select

I have a dataframe which looks like this, and index is `datetime64` of numpy:

```
(index)               data
2017-01-01 00:00:00   1
2017-01-01 01:00:00   2
2017-01-01 02:00:00   3
……                    ……
2017-01-04 00:00:00   73
2017-01-04 01:00:00   nan
2017-01-04 02:00:00   75
……                    ……
```

Now I want to get datas in rolling windows which width are all 72(72 hours) and there is no intersection between two windows such as this:

```
windows1:
(index)               data
2017-01-01 00:00:00   1
2017-01-01 01:00:00   2
2017-01-01 02:00:00   3
……                    ……
2017-01-03 23:00:00   72

windows2:
(index)               data
2017-01-04 00:00:00   73
# data of 2017-01-04 01:00:00 is nan, removed
2017-01-01 02:00:00   75
……                    ……
2017-01-03 23:00:00   144
```

So how can realize this by `DataFrame.rolling` or `DataSeries.rolling`? If there is no easy answer, I will use index itself to solve the problem.

Comment: So rolling("72H") didn't work?

Comment: I saw pandas' document and I think rolling('72H') can only do this: [1H,2H,3H……72H], [2H,3H,4H……73H].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 72H rolling can be achieved with `df.rolling('72H').sum()` (or any other function than `sum`)

But it looks like you don't want a `rolling` but rather a [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`floor`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.floor.html):

```
for k,g in df.groupby(df.index.floor('72H')):
    print(f'New group: {k}\n', g.head(), '\n')
```

output:

```
New group: 2016-12-31 00:00:00
                      data
index                    
2017-01-01 00:00:00     1
2017-01-01 01:00:00     2
2017-01-01 02:00:00     3
2017-01-01 03:00:00     4
2017-01-01 04:00:00     5 

New group: 2017-01-03 00:00:00
                      data
index                    
2017-01-03 00:00:00    49
2017-01-03 01:00:00    50
2017-01-03 02:00:00    51
2017-01-03 03:00:00    52
2017-01-03 04:00:00    53
```

To compute, for example, the mean:

```
df.groupby(df.index.floor('72H')).mean()

            data
index           
2016-12-31  24.5
2017-01-03  73.0
```

###### alternative

```
group = (df.index-df.index[0])//pd.Timedelta('72H')

df.groupby(group).mean()
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'index': pd.date_range('2017-01-01', '2017-01-05', freq='1H'),
                   'data': np.arange(1, 98)}).set_index('index')
```